# Can't execute test from Powershell

Tags: powershell

I'm having a play with Powershell and understanding how to control Visual Studio over the command line in a bid to try to understand the basics of the dev ops world.

If I run this in the command line

```
vstest.console "C:\Users\me\source\repos\Test03\UnitTestProject1\bin\Release\UnitTestProject1.dll"
```

It executes as desired.

If I run the same script from Powershell I get

```
Starting test execution, please wait...
vstest.console : An exception occurred while invoking executor 'executor://mstestadapter/v2': Access to the path 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\TestResults\Deploy_Me 
2018-02-08 14_53_12' is denied.
At C:\Users\me\source\repos\Test03\autostageplan.ps1:12 char:1
+ vstest.console "C:\Users\me\source\repos\Test03\UnitTestProjec ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (An exception oc..._12' is denied.:String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError
```

vstest.console has been set up as an environment variable if that has any impact.

I have read [An exception occurred while invoking executor 'executor://mstestadapter/v1': Object reference not set to an instance of an object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14505003/an-exception-occurred-while-invoking-executor-executor-mstestadapter-v1-obj)

Does any one know why this would be?

Comment: Is your PowerShell window being run as administrator? Looks like just a rights issue to me.

Comment: Well... there you go. Sigh. So obvious. Do you want to mark as an answer @MarkWragg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error occurs because you are not running the PowerShell console with administrator rights (right click PowerShell > Run as Administrator).